# Why does this technique commonly use negative text-indent?

Tags: css, text-indent

Let's say you want to replace an anchor with an image, and you make that image the anchor's background. You still want the text wrapped by the anchor to be there for accessibility reasons, but you don't want it visible. A well known technique is to use something like text-indent: -9999px; along with overflow: hidden;

So let's say our anchor box is 50px x 50px, why wouldn't we just do text-indent: 50px? This would shove the text into the hidden overflow of the anchor, *no matter how long it gets!*

Comment: Pretty sure `overflow` is `visible` by default for most elements?

Comment: There were some weird quirks back in the day where stuff like this only worked if you positioned it to the left, but would be visible when shifted to the right. Hence the negative numbers. I remember building something in IE5 (shudder) or IE6 and realizing that the negative numbers weren't just a trend, they were actually necessary.

Comment: @Graham thank you! That answers *exactly* what I was wondering. If you answer it properly and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: And the reason the text indent number is so large is so that you can define a class (or Sass mixin, etc.) and then apply it to any element without regard to the dimensions of the element and be guaranteed that it will work rather than having to know about the dimensions (which may be dependent upon the browser window size). It's a [DRY](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/curlys-law-do-one-thing.html) thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's just look at what happens when you do that

http://jsfiddle.net/C29Ma/

```
<div class="image">Hide me please</div>

div.image {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/50x50) no-repeat;
    text-indent: 50px;
}
```

Because the text is longer than 50px wide, it wraps around.  Only the very first line is indented by 50px.

The negative indent technique came about before there was widespread support for pseudo elements or controlling word-wrapping.  It does the job well enough, so people don't change how they do things when a newer/better way comes along.

Your suggestion is very close to one of the modern techniques, though

http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/

```
.hide-text {
     text-indent: 100%;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: Alright, weird. I was sure I've done this and it worked but I guess I probably didn't have any breaking spaces in the text. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Personally, I favor this technique, because it works if images are unavailable:  http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-image-replacement-with-pseudo-elements/

Comment: @ryanve If you have a different question, you should ask a new question.

Comment: @ryanve I don't know why you're telling me, I'm not going to answer it.